# Primefaces Translations

Tags: primefaces, translation, message

i'm using primefaces

whan the List of an p:dataTable is empty it shows

```
"No records found."
```

how can i translate it to an other language?

i found datatable uses

```
public java.lang.String getEmptyMessage() {
    return (java.lang.String) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.emptyMessage, "No records found.");
}
```

so i tried adding the key emptyMessage to my message-properties, but this didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the attribute in xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable emptyMessage="#{msg['your.resourcebundlekey']}">
```

Comment: ok... but i have many tables, have i to add this on every single table?

Comment: I don't think there is a better approach than this. One approach that comes into my mind would be to wrap your datatable into a composite component and then set your default values there. but i rather won't do this, makes your code more complex. You could also write a custom DataTableRenderer, but this is even worse...